# Automatically reduce a JPane inside of a JSplitPane to the optimum

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jsplitpane

in my JFrame I got a JPanelSplitPane and a TabbedPane. On the left side of the SplitPane I got a ScrollPane which includes a JTable. On the right side I got a JPanel which includes some formular data like JTextEdit and so on...

One minor problem I got with tje JSplitPane is, that after a program start, the JPane on the right side has a width of e.g. 30% of the whole program frame. When I click on the divider, the right Pane will be reduced on the minimum level.
How can I improve my code in order to automatically set up the minimum level of the right JPanel? Because this size is the perfect one!

Here is my suggestion, but it dont work as expected:

```
int iFrameWidth = getWidth();
int iTableCustomer = scrollPaneCustomer.getWidth();
int iSizePaneDetailCustomer = PaneDetailCustomer.getMinimumSize().width;
int iSizeLeft = iFrameWidth-iTableCustomer-iSizePaneDetailCustomer;
int iDividerLocationCustomer = iSizeLeft+iTableCustomer;
SplitPaneCustomer.setDividerLocation(iDividerLocationCustomer);
```

Comment: Use appropriately configured layout.

Comment: How to achieve a appropriately configured layout? After I clicked on the divider and dragged it into the right side, the minimum size is reached and the divider remains in this position. But I want to have this position directly at program start

Comment: try using `setMinimumSize()` in your right JScrollPane

Comment: I tried it with `setMinimumSize()` for the right JPanel and with `setMaximumSize()` for the left ScrollPane. But it did't work:
`scrollPaneCustomer.setMaximumSize(null);
PaneDetailCustomer.setMinimumSize(null);
SplitPaneCustomer.setDividerLocation(-1);`

Answer (score 0):

> How can I improve my code in order to automatically set up the minimum level of the right JPanel?

Override the getMinimumSize() method of the right panel:

```
@Override
public Dimension getMinimumSize()
{
    return super.getPreferredSize();
}
```